# How i will invoke server control on view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to mvc asp.net,I have already one application created in asp.net 4.0,
but i want to convert that exixting application to asp.net mvc architecture.
In my application every page is having some server control e.g. button, but i am not able to invoke the function associated with the button or server controls.

so, please guide me that how i will proceed so that i can convert my exixting application to mvc architecture.

Comment: Have a look here http://forums.asp.net/t/1528396.aspx/1?MVC+vs+Web+Forms http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-overview-cs it might help you understand mvc better.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web Forms (including pages and server controls) rely on infrastructure provided by ASP.NET page and post-back model. On post-back, the control tree is re-build and state is restored using view-state and then control handles the post-back data to raise events.

ASP.NET MVC does not rely on post-back/view-state rather requests (GET/POST) are routed to appropriate controller actions (along with parameter mapping). The controller methods process the request and sends the response by rendering the view. View's function is just to  accept the data passed by controller and generate corresponding HTML. Now ASP.NET webform (page) can be used as a view but there would be no post-back and no server control events. In ASP.NET MVC, a button click would POST appropriate form to some controller action.

You need to first understand & learn ASP.NET MVC before contemplating the migration.

Further, IMO, there is no point in migrating the application unless it has long shelf life and you foresee a frequent enhancement/maintenance requests in future.